# 3D Touch Peek And Pop on UITableViewCell Objective C Code. (Force Touch)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, 3dtouch, force-touch

I need to enable `Peek And Pop` functionality on a `UITableViewCell` in Objective C by using Force Touch. And also need to show some actions under peek view like default mail app. I am new to iOS and please help me to get there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you taken the [tour] and read the [ask] already?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Peek And Pop Effect on a TableViewCell and Collection View Cell With Actions**

**1)You should address your caller viewController class as UIViewControllerPreviewing Delegate**

@interface MyTableViewController ()

**2)Create a @property for storing the information.**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id previewingContext;
```

**3)Call the forceTouchIntialize method in ViewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self forceTochIntialize];
}
```

**4)Check Force Touch Available or Not**

```
-(void)forceTouchIntialize{
    if ([self isForceTouchAvailable]) {
        self.previewingContext = [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:self.view];
    }
}

- (BOOL)isForceTouchAvailable {
    BOOL isForceTouchAvailable = NO;
    if ([self.traitCollection respondsToSelector:@selector(forceTouchCapability)]) {
        isForceTouchAvailable = self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable;
    }
    return isForceTouchAvailable;
}
```

**5)Specify the view controller which content we want to preview(FOR PEEK)**

```
- (UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id<UIViewControllerPreviewing> )previewingContext viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location{

    CGPoint cellPostion = [yourTableView convertPoint:location fromView:self.view];

    NSIndexPath *path = yourTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:cellPostion];

    if (path) {

        UITableViewCell *tableCell = [yourTableView 

cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

//Pushing to a nib File

        PushViewController *previewController = [[PushViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PushViewController" bundle:nil];

//To Pass data to Preview ViewController

 //       id temp = [yourDataArray objectAtIndex:path.row];

//        PushViewController.anyObject=temp;     

   previewingContext.sourceRect = [self.view convertRect:tableCell.frame fromView: yourTableView

 ];        return previewController;

    }

    return nil;

}
```

**6)POP in a Deep Press (FOR POP)**

```
-(void)previewingContext:(id )previewingContext commitViewController: (UIViewController *)viewControllerToCommit {
    [self.navigationController showViewController:viewControllerToCommit sender:nil];
}
```

**7)When the controller get peek and you swipe up, If you want to add buttons like delete,archive add this method into your previewViewContrller(In this example “ PushViewController")**

```
- (NSArray<id> *)previewActionItems {
    UIPreviewAction *previewAction1 = [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"delete" style:UIPreviewActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIPreviewAction *action,  UIViewController *previewViewController){

    }];

    UIPreviewAction *previewAction2 = [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"archive" style:UIPreviewActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIPreviewAction *action, UIViewController *previewViewController){

    }];
    return @[previewAction1,previewAction2];
}
```